# Firebase firestore rules don't always work on web

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Consider the following rule:

```
    match /triplogs/{anyDocument} {
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.userId;
    }
```

If I hit that with my logged in user, I get the standard:

> Error: FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Missing or insufficient permissions.

### A few points to know:

1. I am indeed logged in, I can output the UID of the current user and it is correct.
2. I can hit this same route via the mobile version and it works.
3. If I remove the `resource.data.userId` check, and just check to see if the user is authenticated (even hard code a uid), it works (so the rule seems to get checked against appropriately)

The simulator says "resources" is null.  I don't understand how the resources object could be null, maybe it's something with the simulator?

Any help would be appreciated, I've troubleshot and googled around for the last few hours with no success.

Query in question:

```js
// ... My firebase wrapper:
import { firebaseApp } from '../utils/firebase';
// ...

const collectionName = 'triplogs';

export const fetchTrips = async (filters?: Filter[]) => {
    let query;
    const ref = db?.collection(collectionName);
    const trips: TripLog[] = [];

    if (filters) {
        filters.forEach((filter) => {
            query = ref?.where(filter.field, filter.operator, filter.value);
        });
    }

    try {
        const obj = query || ref;
        console.log(firebaseApp()?.auth().currentUser?.uid); // <-- this is populated with my logged in UID, FWIW
        const docs = await obj?.get();
        docs?.forEach((doc) => {
            const data = doc.data() as TripLog;
            trips.push({
                ...data,
                id: doc.id
            });
        });

        return trips;
    } catch (err) {
        throw new Error(err);
    }
};
```

Here's the info when I try to run a sample request in the simulator, against those auth rules:

```
{
"path": "/databases/%28default%29/documents/triplogs/%7BanyDocument%7D"
"method": "get"
"auth": {
"uid": "5ompaySrXQcL9veWr3QlSujwlDS2"
"token": {
"sub": "5ompaySrXQcL9veWr3QlSujwlDS2"
"aud": "....omitted"
"firebase": {
"sign_in_provider": "google.com"
}
"email": "...omitted..."
"email_verified": true
"phone_number": ""
"name": "...."
}
}
"time": "2020-10-30T16:48:39.601Z"
}
```

The error in the sim is:

```
Error: simulator.rules line [32], column [58]. Null value error.
```

^^ Which is the resource object

If I change the auth rules to be the following, then I will get back data

```
allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid != null;
```

Data like:

```json
[{
    "createdAt": 1597527979495,
    "name": "Foo Bar Trip",
    "date": 1597527979495,
    "userId": "5ompaySrXQcL9veWr3QlSujwlDS2",
    "id": "FnH2E9WfDkpRHPLXxlDy"
}]
```

But as soon as I check against a field, the "resources" object is null

```
allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.userId;
```

Comment: Without seeing the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with these rules it'll be hard for anyone to say what is going on. Since you claim to be logged in, ensure the code logs the active user right before the call that raises the error, and then include that code and its output in your question.

Comment: We can't see that the client code matches your rules.  Your questions should contain enough information that we can duplicate the issue on our own.

Comment: Sorry, I added a code sample.  If I can get sometime later tonight I'll create a repro app somewhere.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. However, an actual answer/solution should **not** be edited into your question. In general, you should [edit] the question to *clarify* it, but not to include an answer within it. You should create your own answer with the code/solution you used to solve your problem, and then accept it (the system may require a 48 hour delay prior to doing so). When you've solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I'll note you seem to be querying a collection, but your rules seem written for a document... as stated [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions) , rules are not filters - they do not separate out individual documents in a collection.  Are you doing that in your filter[array]?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what else might be going on, but your processing of the filter Array (I do a similar thing) won't work - you are REPLACING the query on each loop, not extending it.  You might try

```
    query = ref;
    if (filters) {
        filters.forEach((filter) => {
            query = query?.where(filter.field, filter.operator, filter.value);
        });
    }
```

to extend the query.

Also, unless your wrapper does more than it shows, your line:

```
        const docs = await obj?.get();
```

"gets" the QuerySnapshot, not the array of docs.  You'd have to do

```
        const docs = await obj?.get().docs;
```

to get the array of actual docs.

Finally, we have no idea (from your above snippets) whether the userID field is even present in your Firestore documents

Comment: I can share a json of the firestore documents to demonstrate useId is populated.  The code works otherwise (as soon as I remove the auth check mentioned).  Good call on the replacement of the query var (durrr...brain fart), thanks.

Comment: I added some more info for clarity's sake.

Comment: Question: *when* was the document written?  Is it possible that *in the simulator* there is a race condition where a recently written document is not actually available *yet* to read?

Comment: Logical question.  In this case, I have records that are seconds old to years old.

Comment: I just wired up "creating" a new trip record and this works fine, has the right userId in there and everything, but querying still doesn't work.

Comment: Ohhh.  I SEE.  Ok ok I was just making an incorrect assumption.  I still have to pass the userId as a query / where filter ... even though the auth rules enforce that.  I incorrect assumed that middleware would apply that filter and not return records where the rule is false.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

I figured it out. I incorrectly assumed the query I was making was auto-filtered by the auth rule (in this case request.auth.id === userId) ... but the auth middleware to firestore doesn't do that. Makes sense. So I just added my filter ... something like this:

```
        fetchTrips([{
            field: 'userId',
            operator: '==',
            value: user.uid,
        }]);
```

This works and returns the correct results. Trying to change the userID correctly throws the auth error too. So that was it.

Comment: BWAHAHAHAH I was just typing the same thing out as a question...

Comment: jinx!  Thanks for the help.